# Avoid "Use of unassigned local variable" error

Tags: c#, closures, action

I have a two methods that are equivalent to this (pardon the contrived example):

```
public void WithResource(Action<Resource> action) {
    using (var resource = GetResource()) {
        action(resource);
    }
}

public void Test() {
    int id;
    SomeObject someObject;

    WithResource((resource) => {
        id = 1;
        someObject = SomeClass.SomeStaticMethod(resource);
    });

    Assert.IsNotNull(someObject);
    Assert.AreEqual(id, someObject.Id);
}
```

(There's some more logic in the WithResource call I'm trying to factor out.)

I'm getting `Use of unassigned local variable` compile-time errors because the assertions
are... using unassigned variables.  I'm currently avoiding the issue by assigning them -1 and `null` respectively.

Initializing to `null` doesn't feel bad, but I'd like to avoid putting the -1 in there... I would really like to tell the compiler "trust me, this will become initialized". Since it's a test, I don't actually care too much if it bombs, because that only means I'll have to fix the test.

I'm tempted to ask if there's a way to give that hint to the compiler, but have the feeling that's even uglier. Does such a hint exist or should I just initialize the variables like I'm doing now?

Comment: In your example you are just passing a lambda function to another method.  The compiler doesn't know if that method will actually execute that lambda function (or when it will choose to do so if it executes it asynchronously).

Comment: If you really want to rely on trust, then use a `dynamic` variable.

Comment: Why don't you put your asserts inside the delegate? that way the compiler will not complain... It might be against AAA but it would do exactly what you want.

Comment: @gunr2171 `dynamic id;` still gives the error.

Comment: @Knaģis you win. some people reading this later may not be able to get away with that, but that's exactly what i'm going to do. plus there's plenty of old tests in the code base that... do not strictly adhere to arrange/act/assert.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compiler is **not smart enough** to determine if the assignment would be made and hence the error.

You can't do anything about it, You have to assign it some default value, probably `0`,`-1`, `default(int)` or `int.MinValue`

Comment: A much better value would be something like -1245678 - something that is very unlikely to be actually used. Also the `id` might not even be set if `GetResource` crashes and if that is the case the behavior might be even worse - that is what the compiler tries to prevent.

Comment: @Knaģis, in that situation probably `int.MinValue` would be better.

Comment: @Knaģis In this particular case if `GetResoruce` throws an exception then the `Assert` won't run.  It is actually provable that in this case the variable won't be used without being assigned.  The issue is that the compiler doesn't look beyond the current scope when determining definite assignability, so it can't make that assertion in this case, even though we as the reader can.  Such proofs, in the general case, are exceedingly difficult to code and time consuming to run, which is why it's not done.

Comment: As an aside, a compiler that was smart enough would need to be able to solve the halting problem

Comment: @ConradFrix However there is still room for improvement between what it currently does and one that can solve definite assignability in the general case.  Writing one to handle this particular case, for example, or some (but not all) of the other false positives, would be possible.

Comment: In this case the two variable are actually converted to _fields_ on some compiler-generated class. For usual fields the compiler does not attempt to check for definite assignment (it is too hard). But here it insists even if the locals are captured by an anonymous function which is "sent off" to other methods.

Answer (score 3):

You should initialize the variables. The compiler will never trust you ;)

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are correct. The easiest way to solve this problem is to initialize the locals.

I assume that you understand why the error is being produced: the compiler has no ability to know that the method called *actually runs the lambda*, and therefore no knowledge that the locals are initialized.

The only way to trick the compiler into not checking whether a variable is assigned is to make the variable non-local:

```
public void Test() {
    int[] id = new int[1];
    SomeObject[] someObject = new SomeObject[1];

    WithResource((resource) => {
        id[0] = 1;
        someObject[0] = SomeClass.SomeStaticMethod(resource);
    });

    Assert.IsNotNull(someObject[0]);
    Assert.AreEqual(id[0], someObject.Id);
}
```

Now you might say, well here I've clearly assigned `id`. Yes, but notice that the compiler does *not* complain that you've used `id[0]` before initializing it!  The compiler knows that array element variables are initialized to zero.